# Set height and width of a cardView in android

Tags: android, imageview, cardview

Im trying to set a width and height for my cardView, so once I download an image from the database, a cardView is added by it stretches the image and can't control the height, im trying to do it programatically. This is what i've got.

```
public void CreateCardView(final Users u) throws IOException

    {
        CardView.LayoutParams params = new CardView.LayoutParams(
                CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(10,10,10,20);
        params.width = 500;

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.containerGrid);
        CardView card = new CardView(this);
        card.setLayoutParams(params);
        card.setRadius(9);

        card.setCardElevation(9);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);
        lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lin.setLayoutParams(par);

        final  ImageButton Name = new ImageButton(this);

        Name.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        Name.setScaleType( ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        mLoginFormView.bringToFront();
        //  Name.setBackground(bdrawable);
        Name.setAdjustViewBounds(true);


        //Name.setImageBitmap(i.getImage().get(0));
        lin.bringToFront();
        mLoginFormView.addView(card);

        card.setElevation(15);
        System.out.println("Hello?");

        //Name.setImageBitmap( scaled);
        TextView username = new TextView(this);
        TextView sport = new TextView(this);
        username.setText(u.getUsername());
        sport.setText(u.getEmail());

        lin.addView(Name);
        lin.addView(username);
        lin.addView(sport);


        card.addView(lin);
        card.setElevation(15);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this code:

```
CardView.LayoutParams params = new CardView.LayoutParams(
                CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(10,10,10,20);
        params.width = 500;
```

Try this code:

```
card.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: So you are creating a new linear layout inside the card